# Creating a custom CAF receiver with <video> element

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to create a custom CAF receiver with my own HTML5 video element and supporting library. Since I'm using my own `<video>` element, I'm setting up the `PlayerManager` instance as follows:

```
// My custom HTML5 video player
const player = new Player(document.querySelector('#my-video'))

const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance()
const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager()
playerManager.setMediaElement(document.querySelector('#my-video'))
// Now, I need to override some of the playerManager methods such as play/pause, etc
const overrides = {
  getCurrentTimeSec () {
    return player.currentTime
  },
  getPlayerState () {
    const PlayerState = cast.framework.messages.PlayerState
    if (!player.ready || !player.source) {
      return PlayerState.IDLE
    }
    return player.paused ? PlayerState.PAUSED : PlayerState.PLAYING
  },
  getDurationSec () {
    return player.duration
  },
  pause: player.pause,
  play: player.play,
  seek: player.seek,
  load: (loadRequestData) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Parse loadRequestData and load the media accordingly
    ...
  })
}
Object.assign(playerManager, overrides)

context.start();
```

Since I need custom handling of the incoming 'load' request in cases where the incoming video is protected, I need to set up a custom `load` handler. My problem seems to be that `playerManager.load` is never called.

Note that all of this works great for normal unprotected HTML5 videos since the incoming `loadRequestData` can be directly understood and used by `PlayerManager`. It is in cases where I need to do some extra processing that things begin to fail.

I have already tried running my business logic as [described by Google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_migrate_to_caf#receiver_business_logic):

```
playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
    cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD,
    request => {
      ...
})
```

The problem in this approach is that even though I'm able to ask my `Player` library to load the video successfully, the intercept needs to either return null or the modified `request`.
When I don't return anything, the `playerManager` thinks that there is no request to load media.
If I do return a 'modified request', then the default media loading logic kicks in which inevitably fails due to the URL being 'malformed'.

In either case, the `playerManager` instance reports not being ready for receiving playback commands.

What is the right approach for setting up a CAF receiver with a custom `<video>` element?

Comment: Currently, custom players are not supported yet for the CAF receiver.

Comment: Should I revert to v2 receiver then? The `cast.receiver.media.Player` seems to have a lot of the same functionality. Any idea if I will be able to use a custom `<video>` element with this class?

Comment: V2 does support a custom media player but v2 has been deprecated.

Comment: Are custom media players still not supported?